# Is there a way to migrate from AWS to GCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, migration

I'm trying to migrate an old project that I were using in AWS into GCP so my questions are:

> 1. Can I migrate all of my Linux VMs without problem?
> 2. Can I migrate all of my IAM permits from one another?

Information about these two cases would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer to both of your questions is **no**. Hit the books, migrating resources from one cloud to another requires a lot of know-how. On the surface AWS and Google Cloud are similar. The details are implemented very differently.

Comment: Will read more about it, thank you for the heads up!

Comment: In software computing, all is possible, it's a matter of skill, budget and time. And as john said, the cloud are similar in surface, but very different in their implementation and concept, and need to rethink, refactor, accept to gain feature and to loose others. It's a real complexe project to migrate from one to another. maybe, a better solution is to accept to perform multicloud and to pilot resource in one cloud provider, from another one and to let the project live where they are the best.

Comment: [Migrate for Compute engine](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.5/how-to/migrate-aws-to-gcp/overview) is a product you can use to migrate an AWS vm to GCP. This lab will give you an idea https://www.qwiklabs.com/focuses/14359?parent=catalog

Comment: Thank you all for your kind answers, I will read about all the topics that you are mentioning me

Comment: @danyL - I agree with you. Practicing with QwikLabs is highly recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Can I migrate all of my Linux VMs without problem?
   This can be achieved with steps mentioned in google cloud public document https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.2/how-to/migrate-aws-to-gcp/overview and you can also use tutorial https://www.qwiklabs.com/focuses/14359?parent=catalog
2. Can I migrate all of my IAM permits from one another?
   Probably no.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).